# Application of Initial Value Theorem

Tags: limits, laplace-transform, wolfram-alpha, initial-value-problems

Let

$$F(s):=\frac{s}{2s-i}$$
be the Laplace transform of some $f(t)$. I have been asked to compute $f(0^+)$ assuming that this quantity, intended as limit, exists.

I thought I could apply the IVT and write

$$ \lim_{t\to 0} \, f(t) = \lim_{s\to \infty} sF(s) = \frac{s^2}{2s-i} = \infty $$

However according to wolfram alpha I should have another [result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20laplace%20transform%20s%2F%282s-i%29): in particular, if I'm not getting wrong

$$ f(t) = \frac{\delta(t)}{2} + \frac{i}{4}\exp \bigg(\frac{it}{2}\bigg) \xrightarrow{t \to 0}\frac{i}{4} $$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Split the integrand in the inverse transform as $(1/2)(1+(i/2)/(s-(i/2))$

Comment: Sorry, don't think I understand your hint, I'm not computing any inverse transform…Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Well, you are given the Laplace transform of $f(t)$ and want to obtain $f(t)$. This follows by applying the inverse transform.

Comment: Well I don't really need to compute the inverse transform but only the limit for $t \to 0$ of the inverse transform. I used wolfram alpha to compute the inverse transform (which should be the one I wrote) just to check that the result was correct, but the fact that I got two different results suggests me that there is something wrong, even if I don't really know where...

Comment: Did you check that the formula you used does apply in the present case? After the splitting the first term directly gives the δ-function contribution of Wolfram which  indicates that distributions are involved.